# How to resolve this error: "KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'" when using iterative_train_test_split in python?

Tags: python

I am attempting to do a train-test-split using iterative_train_test_split. I attempting to use a column of sentences as x and two columns as labels for y. I am new to using iterative_train_test_split and I am just experimenting, but I am lost as to why the error occurs and how to resolve it. I will share the data, my code, and the resulting error below. I found this reference (https://github.com/scikit-multilearn/scikit-multilearn/issues/194), applied np.asmatrix() to both x and y, but still had the same error, so I removed the use of np.matrix() below.

Dataframe:

[image]

Code:

```
x= df['clean_text'] 
y = df[['label','dale_chall_ratio']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = iterative_train_test_split (x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [114], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = iterative_train_test_split (df['clean_text'], y, test_size=0.2)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skmultilearn\model_selection\iterative_stratification.py:95, in iterative_train_test_split(X, y, test_size)
     92 stratifier = IterativeStratification(n_splits=2, order=2, sample_distribution_per_fold=[test_size, 1.0-test_size])
     93 train_indexes, test_indexes = next(stratifier.split(X, y))
---> 95 X_train, y_train = X[train_indexes, :], y[train_indexes, :]
     96 X_test, y_test = X[test_indexes, :], y[test_indexes, :]
     98 return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:984, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    981     key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)
    982     return self._get_values(key)
--> 984 return self._get_with(key)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:999, in Series._get_with(self, key)
    994     raise TypeError(
    995         "Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not "
    996         "supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column"
    997     )
    998 elif isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 999     return self._get_values_tuple(key)
   1001 elif not is_list_like(key):
   1002     # e.g. scalars that aren't recognized by lib.is_scalar, GH#32684
   1003     return self.loc[key]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1034, in Series._get_values_tuple(self, key)
   1031     return result
   1033 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
-> 1034     raise KeyError("key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex")
   1036 # If key is contained, would have returned by now
   1037 indexer, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key)

KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'
```

For replicating purposes:

```
pd.Dataframe({'original_text': {0: "There is manuscript evidence that Austen continued to work on these pieces as late as the period 1809 â '' 11 , and that her niece and nephew , Anna and James Edward Austen , made further additions as late as 1814 .",
      1: "In a remarkable comparative analysis , Mandaean scholar Säve-Söderberg demonstrated that Mani 's Psalms of Thomas were closely related to Mandaean texts .",
      2: 'Before Persephone was released to Hermes , who had been sent to retrieve her , Hades tricked her into eating pomegranate seeds , -LRB- six or three according to the telling -RRB- which forced her to return to the underworld for a period each year .',
      3: 'Cogeneration plants are commonly found in district heating systems of cities , hospitals , prisons , oil refineries , paper mills , wastewater treatment plants , thermal enhanced oil recovery wells and industrial plants with large heating needs .',
      4: 'Geneva -LRB- , ; , ; , ; ; -RRB- is the second-most-populous city in Switzerland -LRB- after Zürich -RRB- and is the most populous city of Romandie -LRB- the French-speaking part of Switzerland -RRB- .'},
     'label': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
     'clean_text': {0: "there is manuscript evidence that austen continued to work on these piece a late a the period 1809 â '' 11 , and that her niece and nephew , anna and james edward austen , made further addition a late a 1814 .",
      1: "in a remarkable comparative analysis , mandaean scholar säve-söderberg demonstrated that mani 's psalm of thomas were closely related to mandaean text .",
      2: 'before persephone wa released to hermes , who had been sent to retrieve her , hades tricked her into eating pomegranate seed , -lrb- six or three according to the telling -rrb- which forced her to return to the underworld for a period each year .',
      3: 'cogeneration plant are commonly found in district heating system of city , hospital , prison , oil refinery , paper mill , wastewater treatment plant , thermal enhanced oil recovery well and industrial plant with large heating need .',
      4: 'geneva -lrb- , ; , ; , ; ; -rrb- is the second-most-populous city in switzerland -lrb- after zürich -rrb- and is the most populous city of romandie -lrb- the french-speaking part of switzerland -rrb- .'},
     'dale_chall_count': {0: 22, 1: 6, 2: 26, 3: 19, 4: 14},
     'token_count': {0: 43, 1: 23, 2: 46, 3: 39, 4: 36},
     'dale_chall_ratio': {0: 0.5116279069767442,
      1: 0.2608695652173913,
      2: 0.5652173913043478,
      3: 0.48717948717948717,
      4: 0.3888888888888889}})
```

Comment: Please check [How to use sklearn train_test_split to stratify data for multi-label classification?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/how-to-use-sklearn-train-test-split-to-stratify-data-for-multi-label-classificat)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it was working for me:

```
from skmultilearn.model_selection import iterative_train_test_split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(np.vstack(x.to_numpy()),y.to_numpy(), test_size = 0.1)
```